# Access method from child to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know how to call child method from parent class. But now, when I want to call a child method from another child I have a problem.

How do I call testMethod() declared in UserAuthenticationRequests class from UserAuthenticationUI class?
It is possible to call testMethod() from App class without problems.

(I dont need to call it from App class just for example)

**Parent class**

```
import React from 'react';
import UserAuthenticationUI from './UserAuthentication/UserAuthenticationUI';
import UserAuthenticationRequests from './UserAuthentication/UserAuthenticationRequests';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.userAuthenticationUI = React.createRef();
        this.userAuthenticationRequests = React.createRef();
    }

componentDidMount(){
    this.userAuthenticationRequests.current.testMethod(); //there i can call method without problems
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <UserAuthenticationUI ref={this.userAuthenticationUI} />
            <UserAuthenticationRequests ref={this.userAuthenticationRequests} />
        <div>
    )}
}
export default App;
```

**1. child where i want to call 2.child method**

```
import React from "react";
import App from '../App';
import UserAuthenticationRequests from './UserAuthenticationRequests';

class UserAuthenticationUI extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.app = React.createRef();
        this.userAuthenticationRequests = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.userAuthenticationRequests.current.testMethod(); //there i can not call
    }

    render(){    
        return(
            <div>
                <App/>
                <UserAuthenticationRequests ref={this.userAuthenticationRequests} />              
            </div>
        )}
    }

    export default UserAuthenticationUI;
```

**Got this error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'testMethod' of null
```

**3. class which is called from parent and 2. child**

```
  class UserAuthenticationRequests extends React.Component {
      testMethod(){
         console.log("test method")
      }

      render(){
          return(<div></div>)
      }
  }
  export default UserAuthenticationRequests;
```

Answer (score 1):

When multiple siblings components want to use the same method or properties, its advisable to lift that state or method up. Also you must use refs in as few cases as possible. In your case you would write it like

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.userAuthenticationUI = React.createRef();
        this.userAuthenticationRequests = React.createRef();
    }

componentDidMount(){
    this.testMethod(); 
}

testMethod(){
     console.log("test method")
}
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <UserAuthenticationUI testMethod={this.testMethod} ref={this.userAuthenticationUI} />
            <UserAuthenticationRequests testMethod={this.testMethod} ref={this.userAuthenticationRequests} />
        <div>
    )}
}
export default App;
```

**UserAuthenticationRequests**

```
  class UserAuthenticationRequests extends React.Component {
      render(){
          return(<div></div>)
      }
  }
  export default UserAuthenticationRequests;
```

**UserAuthenticationUI**

```
class UserAuthenticationUI extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.app = React.createRef();
        this.userAuthenticationRequests = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        this.props.testMethod(); 
    }

    render(){    
        return(
            <div>
                <App/>
                <UserAuthenticationRequests ref={this.userAuthenticationRequests} />              
            </div>
        )}
    }

    export default UserAuthenticationUI;
```

Comment: For right i dont need to call test method from App. it was just example that i am able to do, but not from different class. so, if i will not use userAuthenticationRequests class in App class. i can call it from UserAuthenticationUI?

Comment: In your case, there seems to a circular loop since App rendered `UserAuthenticationUI` and `UserAuthenticationUI` renders `App`

Comment: is there a solution if i will not render App in UserAuthenticationUI?